# Autcorrect sub-menu not available

Tags: autocorrect, word-2013-preview

In older version of word, one could right click on a word, and then have it auto-corrected to a number of different options.

Has the functionality been removed for Word 2013? If not, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

As per [this review](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/software/business-and-finance-software/office-2013-1089108/review/page:2#articleContent):

> And the AutoCorrect features have disappeared from the menu you get when you right-click a spelling mistake; you have to go all the way into Word's huge Options dialog to add corrections you want to use.

Sounds like a stupid change, but the only 'solution' seems to be going into options to specify an AutoCorrect [substitution](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/autocorrect-spelling-and-insert-text-and-symbols-HA010354277.aspx#_Toc311104945) / [exception](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/automatically-correct-spelling-with-words-from-the-main-dictionary-HA010354278.aspx#_Toc252536731) manually:

1. Click the **File** tab.
2. Click **Options**.
3. Click **Proofing** (if you are using Outlook, click **Mail**, and then click **Editor Options**).
4. Click **AutoCorrect Options**.

For exceptions:

5. On the **AutoCorrect** tab, click **Exceptions**, and then click the **Other corrections** tab.
6. Type the misspelled word in the **Don't correct** box.
7. Click **Add**, and then click **OK**.

For substitutions:

5. On the **AutoCorrect** tab, make sure the **Replace text as you type** check box is selected.
6. In the **Replace** box, type a word or phrase that you often mistype or misspell — for example, type *usualy*.
7. In the **With** box, type the correct spelling of the word — for example, type *usually*.
8. Click **Add**, and then click **OK**.

Note #1: When you add a word to the Exceptions list, the word is also added to the default custom dictionary in the spelling checker.

Note #2: The Exceptions list is global across the Office programs that support this feature, which means that any change you make to this list in one program also affects the other programs.

Comment: Does it change anything if I just want more word corrected (as opposed to ignored)?

Comment: AFAIK you can add your own AutoCorrect substitutions (*Replace* <word A> *With* <word B>) as always (like was possible in earlier versions too); only that it will make that correction automatically now unless you add it to the Exceptions list, since the context menu options are gone (who came up with this great idea anyway?)